# Regex expression to match C language numbers

Tags: c++, c, regex, qt, qregexp

I am trying to match numbers in Qt for syntax highlighting, and I am trying the following regexes:

```
"[^a-fA-F_][0-9]+" // For numbers.
"[^a-fA-F_][0-9]+\\.[0-9]+" // For decimal numbers.
"[^a-fA-F_][0-9]+\\.[0-9]+e[0-9a-fA-F]+" // For scientific notation.
"[^a-fA-F_]0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+" // For hexadecimal numbers.
```

But the text is matching, for example, [1024, and highlighting the [ too. I wanted to highlight only the 1024 part.

Another problem is that the regex highlights when I type aoe2 and when I type aoe25. I don't want to highlight the number when it is preceded by letters or underscores, because then it would be an identifier.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Are there not functions for parsing numbers from strings? I know of at least `strto{ul,d}()` but Qt may have more of that?

Comment: Can you provide some sample text and the matches you want? For example, which of these strings you want to match? "aoe2", "aoe25", "1024", "[1024"

Comment: I want to get the position of the numbers on the string, not the numbers themselves, because then the Qt engine will highlight the characters in those positions.

Comment: I don't know whether it is supported in C++ Regex or not, but you need negative look-ahead here.

Comment: I want to match only C numbers, for example: 1024, 4856, 284.582, 0x48e14, 42.42e42, etc. But the regex should not match when those numbers are in identifers, for example "aoe45", and should match (only the number) when they are preceded by operators, for example "[1024]" or "+24".

Comment: Rohit Jain, yeah, I was looking for negative lookbehind, but I don't know if Qt supports that. I couldn't make that work, maybe I made it wrong.

Comment: Note that `09` is not a valid integer in C - having `0` at the beginning means it's octal and `8` or `9` is not octal digit.

Comment: Argh, I forgot that. Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it matches `[` because of this statement:

```
[^a-fA-F_]
This will match anything that is not the letters A-F(any case) or an underscore
```

Why aren't you just matching the digits if that is what you want ?

```
For integers:         \b\d+
For decimal numbers:  \b\d+.\d+
For scientific:       \b\d+e\d+
For hexadecimal:      \b[\dA-Fa-F]+
```

Also as @Jan Dvorak mentions you can use word boundaries `\b`, to make sure your matches begin at the beginning of a word (or number). See example here: http://regex101.com/r/kC6dK3

Comment: He does not want to match the digits if they are for example in a variable like aoe25

Comment: Well, then I should use negative lookbehind? How could I write that, because Qt didn't seem to recognize (?<!a-fA-F_)...

Comment: @RenatoUtsch.. Well, you don't need negative look-behind, rather negative look-ahead like: - `(?![a-fA-F_])`. But may be this also won't be suported.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that Qt doesn't support negative lookbehind, maybe I will need libpcre after all... sad, one more dependency.

Comment: Rohit Jain, the highlighting worked with negative look-ahead, but strings like "aoe25" were still highlighted with: "(?![a-fA-F_])[0-9]+"

Comment: Word `\b`oundary to the rescue!

Comment: OMFG it worked perfectly *---* thank you guys, I won't need libpcre!

Comment: Good answer. One small correction: scientific notation can have a `-` after the `e`. E.g., `1.234e-12`.